# MFC - Problems with CFrameWnd::LoadFrame() in "hello world"

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

So, here's my code (for simplicity I put it all into one file):

```
#include <afxwin.h>
#include "resource.h"

class CMainWnd : public CFrameWnd
{
};

class CApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance()
    {
        CMainWnd* wnd = new CMainWnd();
        if (!wnd->Create(0, _T("test"))) return FALSE;
        m_pMainWnd = wnd;
        wnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
        wnd->UpdateWindow();
        return TRUE;
    }
};

CApp app;
```

It creates simple window with default parameters and title "test". Works perfectly. But then, I want to load my window from resources, so I can put something to it. I replace:

```
        if (!wnd->Create(0, _T("test"))) return FALSE;
```

with

```
        if (!wnd->LoadFrame(IDD_CLIENTWINDOW)) return FALSE;
```

(`IDD_CLIENTWINDOW` is ID of my dialog in resources). LoadFrame returns FALSE, and program exits. There's debug message in output:

```
Warning: failed to load menu for CFrameWnd.
```

But there's no menu in dialog `IDD_CLIENTWINDOW` that I created. How do I load frame correctly? What am I missing?

Comment: Debug into LoadFrame to see which step failed.

Comment: You are missing IDD_CLIENTWINDOW menu resource. This is just the way CFrameWnd::LoadFrame works. If you want to use this function, create menu with such ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying won't work.  LoadFrame() with the ID of a dialog won't load a dialog.  If you want to use a dialog, make CWnd derive from CDialog or use a view derived from CFormView.  Your call to LoadFrame is failing because you don't have a menu resource with the correct ID.  But, you're not really trying to do that.

I recommend you use the AppWizard to generate a new application that is either dialog based or CFormView based and see what kind of code is generated.  You can look at the code to see what you really want to do.